# query select on timestamp field

Tags: sql, h2

I use h2 database.
I have 3 tables: USER, SCHEDULEWORKER and SECURITYACCESS.

USER

```
userNumber, firstName, lastName
```

SCHEDULEWORKER

```
USERNUMBER, STARTDATE, ENDDATE
```

SECURITYACCESS

```
USERNUMBER, DATEACCESS, DOOR
```

`STARTDATE, ENDDATE and DATEACCESS` use timestamp `datatype`.

I would like to get know all user who suppose to work  a day and who entered the maindoor after the start date.

So for this example

```
SCHEDULEWORKER  
USERNUMBER      STARTDATE               ENDDATE  
4141            2012-07-02 07:30:00.0   2012-07-02 16:30:00.0
4123            2012-07-02 07:30:00.0   2012-07-02 16:30:00.0

SECURITYACCESS
USERNUMBER      DATEACCESS      DOOR  
4145    2012-07-02 07:31:56.0   MainDoor
4123    2012-07-02 07:29:56.0   MainDoor
```

I would like to have

```
USERNUMBER  STARTDATE              ENDDATE                DATEACCESS        DOOR        late
4141    2012-07-02 07:30:00.0  2012-07-02 16:30:00.0  2012-07-02 07:31:56.0 MainDoor    00:01:56
```

Do I need to split my field timestamp to be able to do this query?

Comment: What 'work a day' means exactly? work a whole day? work at current day? work from 7:30 to 15:30 or in different hours?

Comment: work a day means have a value for startdate and endate

Comment: Could it be as simple as `select * from SCHEDULEWORKER s, SECURITYACCESS a where s.USERNUMBER = a.USERNUMBER and s.STARTDATE > a.DATEACCESS`?

Comment: begin to be interesting,  
select * from 
SCHEDULEWORKER s, 
SECURITYACCESS a 
where s.USERNUMBER = a.USERNUMBER 
and DATEDIFF(day, STARTDATE, DATEACCESS) = 0 
and a.DATEACCESS > s.STARTDATE  
but people can pass a lot of time by the maindoor, only the first time should be checked, so surely need a subquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be slow but if you have many SECURITYACESS in a day you have to compare first access that day.
I don't work with h2 so you have to manage timestamp calculations for late column

```
select SW.USERNUMBER, STARTDATE, ENDDATE, DATEACCESS, DOOR, (h2 calculations on timestamps) as late
FROM SCHEDULEWORKER AS SW 
  inner join SECURITYACCESS AS SA on SW.USERNUMBER=SA.USERNUMBER
  inner join (SELECT USERNUMBER, MIN(DATEACCESS) as ACCESS
              FROM SECURITYACCESS 
              GROUP BY USERNUMBER, YEAR(DATEACCESS), DAY_OF_YEAR(DATEACCESS)) AS MSA ON SW.USERNUMBER = MSA.USERNUMBER AND MSA.ACCESS = SA.DATEACCESS
WHERE SW.STARTDATE < MSA.ACCESS
```

If you have more where conditions: date range maybe or usernumber as parameter you should change MSA query for better performance.

I didn't found timestamp to date conversion or function for better group by clause.

Comment: a little modified, don't inclue h2 calculation for late...  select SW.USERNUMBER, STARTDATE, ENDDATE, DATEACCESS, DOOR
FROM SCHEDULEWORKER AS SW 
  inner join SECURITYACCESS AS SA on SW.USERNUMBER=SA.USERNUMBER
  inner join (SELECT USERNUMBER, MIN(DATEACCESS) as ACCESS
              FROM SECURITYACCESS 
              GROUP BY USERNUMBER, YEAR(DATEACCESS), DAY_OF_YEAR(DATEACCESS)) AS MSA ON SW.USERNUMBER = MSA.USERNUMBER AND MSA.ACCESS = SA.DATEACCESS
WHERE 
DATEDIFF(day, SW.STARTDATE,  MSA.ACCESS) = 0 
and SW.STARTDATE > MSA.ACCESS